# Is there a useful difference between ISBLANK and =""?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, the `ISBLANK` function seems to effectively behave the same as a comparator of `=""`.  However, the former requires more than double the amount of characters that the latter does.

Is there any useful difference between `ISBLANK` and `=""`?  Are there any situations where it would be particularly preferable to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11):

If a formula is in the cell, but there is no text there, then `=""` will return true, and `=ISBLANK` will be false.

To see this, do `=CONCATENATE(B1,B2)` (where those cells are blank) and test both of those formulas one the cell where you put concatenate.

More simply put (thanks to @Malachi) `ISBLANK` will tell you if the cell is empty, and `=""` will tell you if the display text is empty (note that white-space and invisible characters both count as displayed text).

Comment: so you are saying that `ISBLANK` says whether or not the Cell is Blank, and `=""` says whether the Display Text is empty

Comment: @Malachi that is a much cleaner way of saying it. Mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: i don't mind at all, go ahead :)

Comment: +1, Interestingly COUNTBLANK doesn't differentiate, it counts both true blanks and cells containing ""

Comment: I was always under the impression that `=""` is an **equivalency evaluation** (as in an arithmetic comparison, in a sense), and as such will return `true` for any cell value that *resolves* as `blank`, whereas `=isblank()` is a literal function call that checks for the presence/absence of data input in a cell and returns the respective boolean value.